# PHP PDO returns bool false sorta

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

When i run the code and var dump result it gives bool false. I made a mistake typing and was holding shift and 0 on the right number key pad, it echohed  http://sales/form2.php in the input box. I backed spaced it out and put the correct info in and it works as expected. I don't know if its the code or my system Ubuntu 18.10

```
    <?php
/*include ('includes/validation.php');*/
include ('includes/validationmysql.php');



/*$dbh = new PDO("pgsql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);*/
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sales', $dbuser, $dbpass);

if(!$dbh) {
      echo "Error : Unable to open database\n";
   } else {
      echo "Opened database successfully\n";
   }

if(isset($_POST["custID"])){
$custID=$_POST["custID"];

 $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT CustFirstName, CustLastName, CustAddress, CustCity, CustState, CustZip, CustCellPhone
         FROM customers WHERE custID = '".$custID."'"); 
         $sql->execute();
         $result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

var_dump($custID);

var_dump($result);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Form</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Figure It Out</h1>
<form action="" method="post">
<p>CustomerID <input  type="text" name="custID" value="<?php  echo $custID; ?> " size="5"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></p>

  <textarea>
  <?php
  echo $result['CustFirstName']. ' ' . $result['CustLastName']. "\n";
  echo $result['CustAddress']. "\n";
  echo $result['CustCity']. ' ' . $result['CustState']. ' ' . $result['Custzip']. "\n";
  echo $result['CustCellPhone'];
  ?>
  </textarea>


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's not clear (at least to me) what the exact problem is in which scenario. _"and it works as expected"_ - the shown code works as expected?? When do you get false for result then?

Comment: IF you enter into the input ex;(DAV123)box and submit it gives bool false for result.

Comment: IF you enter into the input ex;(DAV123)box and submit it gives bool false for result. I accidentally held the shift key when I was entering the number part 123 which just highlighted the letters, when I backed it out and reentered it gave the correct results. So the only way it works properly is if you hold shift and hit a number on number key pad on the right. I have tried other combinations of shift and numbers at top just trying to figure it out but it only works with the numbers on the right side. beats me

Answer (score 1):

You are vulnerable to SQL injections, because you use prepared statements not properly.

```
$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT CustFirstName, CustLastName, CustAddress, CustCity, CustState, CustZip, CustCellPhone 
                      FROM customers WHERE custID = '".$custID."'"); 
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

must read as follows:

```
$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT CustFirstName, CustLastName, CustAddress, CustCity, CustState, CustZip, CustCellPhone 
                      FROM customers WHERE custID = ? "); 
$sql->execute([$custID]);
$result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Thanks for bring that to my attention